# Background image not scalling on mobiles

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a website on Wordpress with the following code for one of the sections but it the image is not fitting on mobile phones please advice

```css
    .one_half_bg {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-position: 50% 50% !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you need `media query` for that. The other thing is, that can be easily achieve using google search engine with the keywords `background image responsive mobile`

Comment: instead of using `img tag` use `background-image` css property and place  the image

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the background and container aspect ratios, using `cover` might make the image get cut off because you're forcing it to cover the entire area of the container. If you want the image to be fully visible, but not necessarily cover the container, use `background-size: contain;`.

Also, use media queries to make it behave differently on different screen sizes, if that's what you want. Hard to know unless you post most context.